# not able to upload image from users but able from admin in django

Tags: python, django

i am not able to upload an image from html page but it is possible from admin page
here is my models.py:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance,filename):
  return "image/%s_%s"%(str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)

class Company_Profile(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 name = models.CharField(_('Company Name'), max_length= 30)
 logo = models.FileField(_('Company Logo'), upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
 address = models.TextField(_('Contact Address'), max_length=50)
 phone_no = models.IntegerField(_('Contact No'), max_length=12)
```

my views.py:

```
def company_prof(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    comp_prof = Company_Prof(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if comp_prof.is_valid():
        save_prof = comp_prof.save(commit=False)
        save_prof.user = request.user
        save_prof.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Thank you for Registration')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('company/'+str(save_prof.id))
 else:
    comp_prof =Company_Prof()
 variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'comp_form': Company_Prof()})
 return render_to_response("comp_profile.html",
                          locals(),
                          context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

my settings.py is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT ='G:\Mini project\Pycharm projects\project4\static/'
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

html page is:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="global_form"            action="" method="post"><div><div><h3>Create Account</h3>
<div id="connect_signup_box" class="connect_box_form clearfix">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ comp_prof.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">
    {% if save_prof %}
    <h3>The details are submitted</h3>

    {% endif %}
  <input type="reset" class="btn" value="cancel">
   {% if value == 'cancel' %}
   <h3>Canceled</h3>
   {% endif %}
   </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

when i submit it says no files are chosen. but from admin page there is no problem.
help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you have nested forms, which isn't supported by browsers ([Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)).

So I am assuming that the browser is just using the first form definition, which has the wrong enctype. Try removing the first form declaration and just keeping this one: `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.